# Differentiating x using chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question is

$\frac{d}{dx} [\sin(e^x)]^{\log_{e}x}$

I don't know how to proceed as the power and the base are varying with x

It's kind of like $x^x=f(x)$

So I don't know whether this right or not?

A hint would be appreciated

The answer is

$[lnx*\cot(x) + \frac{\ln(\sin(e^x))}{x}]*[\sin(e^x)^{\ln x}$

Comment: Where is your problem exactly? If you know how to apply the chain rule I cannot see any problems..

Comment: Do you know about logarithmic differentiation?

Comment: So should we first differentiate $lnx$ and then $sin (e^x)$ and so on......?

Comment: $f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{g(x)\operatorname{log}_e(f(x))}$, so the derivative is: $f(x)^{g(x)}$ **times** the derivative of $g(x)\operatorname{log}_e(f(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\sin(e^x)^{\ln(x)}$$
$$\implies\ln(y)=\ln(x)\ln(\sin(e^x))$$

Now, differentiating both sides wrt. $x$, $$\frac1y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\ln(x)\cdot\ln(\sin(e^x))\bigg)$$ Now, use the product rule of differentiation on the right hand side and for the derivative of the second term, use chain rule on $\ln(\sin(e^x))$

This method is known as logarithmic differentiation. Don't forget to multiply  both sides by $y$ in the end and on the R.H.S. replace $y$ by $\sin(e^x)^{\ln(x)}$.

Comment: Ok thank you
I totally forgot about taking log on both sides!!!

Comment: @Student4 Great! Happy to help. If you find it helpful, you can accept the answer :)